# cbind dataframes containing varying numbers of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have several dataframes that contain largely the same variables, but some variables are missing from certain dataframes. I would like to cbind (one particular column of*) the dataframes while creating NA values in the missing fields. By way of example:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var2", "var3"),
                 y2 = c(3, 2, 4),
                 y3 = c("not_needed", "not_needed2", "not_needed3"))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var3"),
                 y2 = c(2, 1),
                 y3 = c("not_needed", "not_needed2"))
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var2", "var4"),
                 y2 = c(3, 2, 5),
                 y3 = c("not_needed", "not_needed2", "not_needed3"))

expected_output <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"),
                              y2.d1 = c(3, 2, 4, NA),
                              y2.d2 = c(2, NA, 1, NA),
                              y2.d3 = c(3, 2, NA, 5))
```

*The column `y3` is not required in the output dataframe.

I've experimented with `rbind.fill()` from `plyr` and a few other ideas, but no success so far.

@joran I don't believe that this is a duplicate of the linked question, as I'm not trying to merge the entire dataframes, just one column from each. I appreciate that the answer is probably in there somewhere, but it's not specifically mentioned.

Comment: It should be noted that the title of this question does not match the example. All those dataframes have length==3.

Comment: I intuitively thought that "length of a dataframe" == "nrow(dataframe)". I've edited title to "...varying numbers of rows". Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's a common source of erroneous R coding.

Comment: Hah. I'm seeing this for a second time in the reopen queue b/c I was about to post a base-R solution and it got closed before I hit 'post': `Reduce( function(x,y) merge(x,y[-3],by="y1", all=TRUE), list(d1[-3],d2,d3) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). We can put all data frame in a list and then use functions from [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) to merge it. Notice that I use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the example data frames to prevent factor columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

d_list <- list(d1, d2, d3)

d_final <- d_list %>%
  map(select, y1, y2) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "y1") %>%
  setNames(c("y1", paste0("y2.d", 1:3)))

d_final
#     y1 y2.d1 y2.d2 y2.d3
# 1 var1     3     2     3
# 2 var2     2    NA     2
# 3 var3     4     1    NA
# 4 var4    NA    NA     5
```

**DATA**

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var2", "var3"),
                 y2 = c(3, 2, 4),
                 y3 = c("not_needed", "not_needed2", "not_needed3"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var3"),
                 y2 = c(2, 1),
                 y3 = c("not_needed", "not_needed2"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d3 <- data.frame(y1 = c("var1", "var2", "var4"),
                 y2 = c(3, 2, 5),
                 y3 = c("not_needed", "not_needed2", "not_needed3"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```